# Pinging My IP and 8.8.8.8

Tags: ip, ping

If I ping my own public static IP, it gives me latency of around 20 ms whereas pinging 8.8.8.8 gives latency around 10 ms. Why is this so? Could this be a DHCP issue as I got to know that my router is given a local IP and all packets are manually forwarded through my ISP's dhcp server. But still shouldn't pinging 8.8.8.8 get more latency?

Comment: 8.8.8.8 is an anycast address, it pings to the nearest host to your location so latency can be very small. Apart from that, i'm not sure why pinging your IP would have a bigger latency.

Comment: Ping latency cannot necessarily be compared across devices. // DHCP servers don’t forward packages. Do you really have a public static IP?

Comment: @DanielB I do have public static IP.

Comment: Ping answering is one of the services with the least priority. So the system which you ping will answer when (or even if) it has free time for answering. Do not forget about firewall which may delay the answer too.

Comment: @Akina No, as I said, Pinging my local IP gives me ping of less than 1ms.